# On Constructing Universal One-Way Hash Functions from Arbitrary One-Way Functions | Claim 9 Proof Clarification

Tags: one-way-function

I'm reading Katz and Koo's paper that constructs UOWHFs from OWFs. I'm trying to rigorously understand every proof, and I'm having a hard time understanding an equality. This lemma is trying to prove that it suffices for adversary B to invert the output of a OWF when the output is in $image_{\frac{l}{2}}$. I specifically don't understand the last equality. Don't we need to assume that the probability of B inverting $\bar{z}$ is identical for every $\bar{z}$ for the equality to hold? Why does the equality hold if we don't need the assumption? I'm assuming I'm forgetting a simple probability concept here, so I'd appreciate a pointer to that concept as well.

Here's a link to the paper: [https://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/papers/rompel.pdf](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Ejkatz/papers/rompel.pdf)

[image: Here's the 's the proof]

Comment: please put a link to the paper itself (unpaywalled preferably) as well

Comment: This is because the size of the set defined as $\textsf{image}_{\ell/2}$ is crucial to the question